# how do i use np.nanmin when comparing one column of pandas dataframe with a integer?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, np.nan]])
np.nanmin(a, axis=0)
array([1.,  2.])
```

I want to use same logic but on pandas dataframe columns and comparing each value of column with an integer.

use case:

```
MC_cond = df['MODEL'].isin(["MC"])
df_lgd_type = df['LGD_TYPE'].isin(["FIXED"])
df_without_lgd_type = ~(df_lgd_type)

x = np.nanmin((1,df.loc[MC_cond & df_without_lgd_type,'A'] + df.loc[MC_cond & 
    df_without_lgd_type,'B']))
```

comparing sum of column A and column B with 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick even without `np.nanmin`. I hope I've understood everything correctly from your sparse description.

I'm assuming you also want to replace those `NaN` values that are left after summation. So we fill those with `1` and then clip all values to max at `1`.

```
a = df.loc[MC_cond & df_without_lgd_type, 'A']
b = df.loc[MC_cond & df_without_lgd_type, 'B']
x = (a + b).fillna(1).clip(upper=1)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [-1, np.nan, 2, 3, 4], 
    'B': [-4, 5, np.nan, 7, -8]
})

(df.A + df.B).fillna(1).clip(upper=1)

# Output:
# 0   -5.0
# 1    1.0
# 2    1.0
# 3    1.0
# 4   -4.0
# dtype: float64
```

In case you don't want NaN values in one column leading to row sum being NaN too, just fill them before:

```
x = (a.fillna(0) + b.fillna(0)).fillna(1).clip(upper=1)
```

---

Just for completeness, this would be a pure *numpy* solution resembling your approach:

```
a = df.loc[MC_cond & df_without_lgd_type, 'A'].to_numpy()
b = df.loc[MC_cond & df_without_lgd_type, 'B'].to_numpy()

# optionally fill NaNs with 0
# a = np.nan_to_num(a)
# b = np.nan_to_num(b)

s = a + b
x = np.nanmin(np.stack(s, np.ones_like(s))), axis=0)
```

Comment: That's an incredibly useful feedback, please excuse my sarcasm.